# Classic ASP - How to pass a variable instead querystring (refresh) via Jquery(no refresh)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic

i'm working on this application that has a calendar on a page that has a lot of request.form("var") inside.
This is a monthly calendar and it has on the top previous month and next month .
When i click now on next month i get an URL like: ?date=8/14/2010 
My question is how to pass this value to the calendar via jquery with no page refresh .. because if i use page refresh i loose  the request.form("values") 
Hope i make myself understand , 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you use AJAX, you can send requests and get information without refreshing the page.  As far as I know, JQuery has some functions built in to make AJAX pretty easy.

Another common way this is done is to use the anchor rather than the query string (e.g. http://example.com/page.asp#8/14/2010), because then you can still link directly to the page as it is, and changing the anchor doesn't cause the page to refresh and can be red by JavaScript.  GMail and Facebook both use this, which is why you can scroll through pictures fast without reloading the page for every picture.